# How to reduce object size webgl?

Tags: three.js

Is there some functions for webgl, like  culling si clipping in opengl?
For example if i have an object with 100K vertices, can i load object in front high quality, and back low quality, to reduce from vertices? I read that camera from three.js do something like that. Thanks

Comment: For an example take a look at http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod and for the documentation at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/LOD

Comment: Exact what I want. Thanks a lot.